Chain approach for Langchain is not able to handle longer prompts
I have two datasets I need to compare and give an output for. So for example, if dataset 1 has a list of items, I want it to compare across dataset 2 and return a mapping like this.



Dataset 1
Dataset 2




Germany
Deustchland


Turkey
Turkiye



I'm not actually using countries, but it's a bit like a fuzzy match of sorts.
I am currently testing out chains in langchain and using dataset 1 as the input data and then adding a couple of items from dataset 2 in the query. It works fine for a couple of items, but does not work for a larger number. Hence, I wanted to look for ways where I could generate an output without exceeding the prompt limit and getting accurate output.
Using map_reduce or refine gives me this error
ValidationError: 1 validation error for RefineDocumentsChain prompt  Extra inputs are not permitted [type=extra_forbidden, input_value=PromptTemplate(input_vari...IZED TESTS: {question}'), input_type=PromptTemplate]
